# SQL query from XML Column stored as nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i need help with sql query. I have table with column, where is stored xml as nvarchar.

| XmlCurves |
| --- |
| `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>` |

All XML looks like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Curve xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Anchor>Begin</Anchor>
  <LoadOnlyNOKCurves>false</LoadOnlyNOKCurves>
  <Teachmode>false</Teachmode>
  <ActualCurve>
    <FloatPoints>0;4.965425|0.01004791;5.438642|0.01076508;5.50529|0.01112366;5.485298</FloatPoints>
  </ActualCurve>
  <AbsOffset>
    <X>88.21842</X>
    <Y>0</Y>
  </AbsOffset>
  <UpperLimit>
    <FloatPoints>9.456265E-05;5.023251|0.008893617;5.502031</FloatPoints>
  </UpperLimit>
  <LowerLimit>
    <FloatPoints>0.0008510638;4.906321|0.01408511;5.495711</FloatPoints>
  </LowerLimit>
  <ULViolationCurveIdx>-1</ULViolationCurveIdx>
  <ULViolationULIdx>-1</ULViolationULIdx>
  <LLViolationCurveIdx>-1</LLViolationCurveIdx>
  <LLViolationLLIdx>-1</LLViolationLLIdx>
  <SIO_X>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Alias>Position</Alias>
    <Unit>mm</Unit>
  </SIO_X>
  <SIO_Y>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Alias>Force</Alias>
    <Unit>kN</Unit>
  </SIO_Y>
</Curve>
```

And i need built SQL query, which select data in first tag FloatPoints: `<FloatPoints>0;4.965425|0.01004791;5.438642|0.01076508;5.50529|0.01112366;5.485298</Floatpoint>`

For explanation:

```
<FloatPoints>x1;y1|x2;y2|x3;y3|x4;y4</FloatPoints>
```

Therefore, I would like this result:

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.965425 | 0.01004791 | 5.438642 | 0.01076508 | 5.50529 | 0.01112366 | 5.485298 |

If at all possible.

Comment: *"where is stored xml as nvarchar."* Why are you storing XML in an `nvarchar` when there's an `xml` data type.

Comment: Also, do you *really* just want 8 columns with the `varchar` value `'number'` in them? If so, I don't see why you need to read the XML do that that, you could just do `SELECT 'number' AS x1, 'number' AS y1, ..., 'number' AS x4, 'number' AS y4;`

Comment: @Larnu This is due to the origin of this data from the software that generates the data. Unfortunately, I am not able to influence this property. Maximum using integration services, but there will still be a problem with parsing.

I need the given values from that column(XmlCurves) in the given tag(FloatPoints). I don't care which way. But these values are stored only in this column, which is XML. But it is preserved as an nvarchar :-(

I need the given values from that column(XmlCurves) in the given tag(FloatPoints). I don't care which way.

Comment: So what is your *actual* expected results here?

Comment: My expected results are values in FloatPoints tags.  Column `X1` with value `0`, Column `Y1` with value `4.965425` . Column `X2` with value `0.01004791`, column `Y2`  with value `5.438642`  and so for all values in tag.

Comment: update your qusetion to show what the expected results you actually want are, @Cesc . Use the [edit] feature.

Comment: Is FloatPoints tag always 4 points long?

Comment: @Larnu Ok, i will edit.

Comment: @Serg Not always, but it will be enough for me to be able to ask this query for this use case.

Comment: @Larnu Looks like OP's issue with storing as `xml` might be due to encoding

Comment: @Charlieface you'll need to convert the value to a `varchar` first, and *then* you can convert it to `xml`.

Comment: @Charlieface [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=368153f7a93fd09834972b85a354a607)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a few assumptions:

- The XML is always a valid `xml` value.
- There are always 4 xy coordinates
- That the lengths of x & y's values cannot be longer than 127 characters.
- The value wanted it in the node `ActualCurve`
- You are on a version that supports `TRANSLATE` (if not, use nested `REPLACE`s)

With this assumptions in place you can do the following:

1. Convert the `nvarchar` to a valid `xml` value
2. Extract the value of `Curve/ActualCurve/FloatPoints`
3. Replace the characters to create a value that can use `PARSENAME` to separate the separate parts into
4. Use `CHARINDEX` to get the correct left/right part of the string
5. `CONVERT` back to a `float`

```sql
DECLARE @XMLLikeString nvarchar(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Curve xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Anchor>Begin</Anchor>
  <LoadOnlyNOKCurves>false</LoadOnlyNOKCurves>
  <Teachmode>false</Teachmode>
  <ActualCurve>
    <FloatPoints>0;4.965425|0.01004791;5.438642|0.01076508;5.50529|0.01112366;5.485298</FloatPoints>
  </ActualCurve>
  <AbsOffset>
    <X>88.21842</X>
    <Y>0</Y>
  </AbsOffset>
  <UpperLimit>
    <FloatPoints>9.456265E-05;5.023251|0.008893617;5.502031</FloatPoints>
  </UpperLimit>
  <LowerLimit>
    <FloatPoints>0.0008510638;4.906321|0.01408511;5.495711</FloatPoints>
  </LowerLimit>
  <ULViolationCurveIdx>-1</ULViolationCurveIdx>
  <ULViolationULIdx>-1</ULViolationULIdx>
  <LLViolationCurveIdx>-1</LLViolationCurveIdx>
  <LLViolationLLIdx>-1</LLViolationLLIdx>
  <SIO_X>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Alias>Position</Alias>
    <Unit>mm</Unit>
  </SIO_X>
  <SIO_Y>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Alias>Force</Alias>
    <Unit>kN</Unit>
  </SIO_Y>
</Curve>';

SELECT CONVERT(float,LEFT(xy1,CHARINDEX(';',xy1)-1)) AS x1, 
       CONVERT(float,STUFF(xy1,1,CHARINDEX(';',xy1),'')) AS y1,
       CONVERT(float,LEFT(xy2,CHARINDEX(';',xy2)-1)) AS x2, 
       CONVERT(float,STUFF(xy2,1,CHARINDEX(';',xy2),'')) AS y2,
       CONVERT(float,LEFT(xy3,CHARINDEX(';',xy3)-1)) AS x3, 
       CONVERT(float,STUFF(xy3,1,CHARINDEX(';',xy3),'')) AS y3,
       CONVERT(float,LEFT(xy4,CHARINDEX(';',xy4)-1)) AS x4, 
       CONVERT(float,STUFF(xy4,1,CHARINDEX(';',xy4),'')) AS y4
FROM (VALUES(@XMLLikeString))V(XMLLikeString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml,CONVERT(varchar(MAX),V.XMLLikeString))))TC(XML)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TC.XML.value('(Curve/ActualCurve/FloatPoints/text())[1]','varchar(4000)')))AC(FloatPoints)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRANSLATE(AC.FloatPoints,'.|',',.')))T(FloatPoints)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(PARSENAME(T.FloatPoints,4),',','.'),REPLACE(PARSENAME(T.FloatPoints,3),',','.'),REPLACE(PARSENAME(T.FloatPoints,2),',','.'),REPLACE(PARSENAME(T.FloatPoints,1),',','.')))PN(xy1,xy2,xy3,xy4);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07e067e7f1782e76b6c40971aa1cfe9b)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving encoding apart, the problem is preserving item positions while parsing a FloatPoints tag. Unfortunately `string_split` is not guaranteed to preserve item positions so you may need a custom splitter ( `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` here) which returns item position as well.

```
select id,
   Max(case t2.itemnumber*100 + t3.itemnumber when 101 then cast(t3.Item as decimal(10,6)) end) x1,
   Max(case t2.itemnumber*100 + t3.itemnumber when 102 then cast(t3.Item as decimal(10,6)) end) y1,
   Max(case t2.itemnumber*100 + t3.itemnumber when 201 then cast(t3.Item as decimal(10,6)) end) x2,
   Max(case t2.itemnumber*100 + t3.itemnumber when 202 then cast(t3.Item as decimal(10,6)) end) y2
...
from (select id, cast(txn_message as xml) x
      from tbl) a
cross apply a.x.nodes('Curve/ActualCurve/FloatPoints') t(n)
cross apply DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(t.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(200)') , '|') t2
cross apply DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(t2.Item, ';') t3
group by id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e2a572534aed5029192b7748564f2f5)

Includes `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`.